# How do I show select dropdown from an API response in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that gets a list of projects from a MOCK API and I wish to get the projects list and list them inside a select dropdown using React. This is what I've tried and I've gotten stuck. Please don't be mean with the responses, I'm still new as a React Developer and I am learning as I go.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const getProjects = () => {
    axios.get('/api/projects', {
        header: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        return res.data
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex)
    })
}

const Dropdown = () => {
    
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getProjects()
    })

    return(
        <div>
                       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dropdown
```

I've iterated through a couple of solutions and they all aren't working. The API sits here
[MOCK API](https://mock-api.binaryboxtuts.com/)

**EDIT**
this is how far I've progressed with the suggestions

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const getProjects = () => {
    axios.get('/api/projects', {
        header: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        return res.data
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex)
    })
}

const Dropdown = () => {
    
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])    

    useEffect(() => {
        getProjects(setProjects)
    }, [])

    return(
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="select">Class Name</label>
            <select>
                {projects.map(project => {
                    return <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>{project.name}</option>
                })}
            </select>                       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dropdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change the state and you do nothing with the value returned from the AJAX request. You need to use something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const getProjects = (done) => {
    axios.get('/api/projects', {
        header: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        done(res.data);
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex);
    });
};

const Dropdown = () => {
    
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getProjects(setProjects);
    });

    
    return (
      <div>
        <select>
         {projects.map(project => {
            return (
              <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>
                {project.name}
              </option>
            );
         })}
        </select>
       </div>
    );
};

export default Dropdown
```

You also need:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        getProjects(setProjects);
    }, []);
```

So the AJAX request happens only on the component mount and not on every update (which may cause an infinite loop).

You can also make the fetch into a custom hook:

```
const useProjects = () => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('/api/projects', {
        header: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setProjects(res.data);
      })
      .catch((ex) => {
        console.log(ex);
      });
    }, []);

    return projects;
};

const Dropdown = () => {
    const projects = useProjects();
    
    return (
      <div>
        <select>
         {projects.map(project => {
            return (
              <option key={project.id} value={project.id}>
                {project.name}
              </option>
            );
         })}
        </select>
       </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks jcubic, that paved a way but the method ```done``` does not exist. I tried to replace it with ```return res.data``` and console.log ```projects``` inside ```Dropdown``` but it returns an empty object.

Comment: @KwaneleSimelane `done` is `setProjects` your setState function. Can you show the code you have after the changes I suggested? Add `**EDIT**` and put it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: please see the changes

Comment: @KwaneleSimelane you don't have my exact code I modified `getProjects` function,

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for walking me through. I have found the way with your help. I'll go ahead and mark this as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

**your code contain more errors**

1. function getProject is still wait response the when use return will get undefined or null
2. in useEffect you will give you error,because have unlimited run project
3. after call function dont put data response in right place

**for correct your code and working must follow this tips**

4. function getProject convert him to Promise
5. use this sentence useEffect(function(){},[]) for calling at once
6. if you use promise getProject then put data response in right place setProject(data.response)

> **if you still have any question or help i'm here you must notify me also if you need correct code**

Comment: Hey @ismail, could you please be more specific. Especially with your last point